# Getting file descriptor to Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a code library that was built with assumptions that all file IO was via file descriptors. It relies heavily on assuming that any input data can be accessed via file descriptors, whether they be files, or network data.

We would like to try moving some of the data to Amazon S3, but would like to avoid s3fs if possible. I looked through some of the AWS S3 docs for the C++ library, but I couldn't find anything that allowed you to get a file descriptor which you could use to read/select/poll etc.

Did I miss anything? Does Amazon have a more C based API for S3?

Comment: Use _sockets_? These are based on fd's.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sockets and fds are only compatible if you are using Posix.  They aren't on Windows

Comment: @MartinBonner Good point.

Comment: @MartinBonner - No mention that this has to be cross platform

Comment: @bpeikes No mention of what the target platform is either.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is an object storage system. It does *not* present itself as a traditional file system.

Some software products that present S3 as a file system:

- s3fs: Not recommended for production usage. Users report many problems.
- [AWS Storage Gateway as a File Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/StorageGatewayConcepts.html#file-gateway-concepts): Reliable NFS gateway to Amazon S3
- [Cloudberry Drive for Windows Server](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-cloud-server-drive.aspx)
- [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/)

Depending upon how you wish to use the files, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which as a `aws s3 sync` command that can synchronize files with the cloud (in either direction). Think of it like a DropBox solution. That way, you could have a local copy of the files to access through a file descriptor.

Comment: I understand that it is an object storage system, though it sounds like AWS Storage Gateway would give access to files as if they were nfs, which means you can get file descriptors.
I know that S3 does not present as a traditional file system. I was asking if any of Amazon's libraries give you access via file descriptor. File descriptors don't have to be files, they work for sockets, pipes and other communication endpoints. Amazon could have written a library that gives the user a file descriptor which could connect an S3 file.